# How to effectively manage the ML code deployment via gradle to multiple ML cluster enviorments

Tags: gradle, pipeline, marklogic

The recommended MarkLogic automation is via Gradle.

I wonder where there should a dedicated single VM to run those Gradle tasks to control the configuration and deployment to different Prod / UAT / Test / Dev ML cluster enviroments.

**Is my below understanding correct?**

One single dedicated VM should be specifically **included** in the overall design to hande ML configuration deployment for different ML enviroments.

- Gradle is not required in each ML hosts. Gradle should be only used in that ML management depot.
- In each gradle properties, the load balancer IP for each ML enviroment cluster should be used.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsh1O.png

**Scope of that [ML Management Depot] VM**

1. ML XQuery Git  deployment pipeline
2. Any post deployment tasks like postman script execution or additional xquery execution
3. MLCP tasks
   (a) Data Sync  Prod → UAT → Test → Dev
   (b) Documents ingestion (XML, PDF, HTML, others)
   (c) Documetns export for raw files backup to Azure Data Lake
4. Corbs tasks - bulk data update and report

(All those should be configured as gradle tasks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely a good strategy - one separate machine/host/whatever to handle deployment (Gradle) and batch processing (MLCP/Corb) tasks. As you note, you don't need Gradle (nor MLCP or Corb) available on any of the hosts. For MLCP and Corb in particular, it's best to run those on a separate machine so that they're not competing for system resources with any of the ML hosts.

Comment: May I know whether it makes sense to place that Gradle node in front of the Load Balancer? Whether that Node could still work with Session Afflinity Load Balancer? (Basiecally I want to check whether it could still distribute the load to the clustered ML, if the Corb routine is from single Gradle node.) My worry is that **Session Affinity**. Or does it mean "try" not not use any xquery model library from the module db in order to be compliant with Session Affinity?

Comment: It depends what tool you're talking about. MLCP has a config setting to work with a load balancer. ml-gradle doesn't care what host or LB it's talking to. I believe Corb is the same way.